# Loading sound resource to play it Java

Tags: java, audio, resources

I know there are many post about the topic but I can´t find a solution to my problem, I am trying to load a .wav file and play it.

Source code:

```
package main;

import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Sounds {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    play("click.wav");
}
public static void play(String filename)
{
    try
    {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename)));
        clip.start();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

}
Stack Trace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: click.wav (The system could not find the specified file)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at main.Sounds.play(Sounds.java:18)
at main.Sounds.main(Sounds.java:11)
```

Folder Hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Also, are you sure the extra whitespace in the filename on the line `play("  click.wav");` won't affect anything?

Comment: @RandomDavis the whitespace does not affect it seems. Sorry for not explaining the problem, basically when executing that code, a FileNotFoundException arises

Comment: I don't think java's going to default to looking in the current directory it's executing in to find that file - also, when running are you running it from what looks to be eclipse or from a command line?  In eclipse, you'd need the full url to the file and from the command line it would depend on if it's a standalone class file or packaged as a jar - a jar you'd need to use the getResourceAsStream format to get the file and you'd likely want to put it in the META-INF folder.  If you can answer those questions then I can see if I can give you a working example

Comment: I´m running the code from Eclipse, I tried using the URL of the file but I had a similar problem

Comment: `I tried using the URL of the file but I had a similar problem` - how did you specify the URL? See [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource). It should work for any resource.

Comment: @camickr I tried again to use the URL and it worked, weird since I tried more than once using the URL but maybe some typo declaring the filename. Thank you for the feedback